# The resulting image file is even larger than original when using K-means to do image compression

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, k-means

I am trying to compress jpeg file

[Original Picture]

[image]

[Compressed Picture with K-means using K=10]

[image]

However, the original one is 85K while the compressed one is 101K?

Here is the code I use:

````
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.image import imread
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray
%matplotlib inline
# test_pic="image.png"
test_pic="monalisa1.jpg"
# img = imread(test_pic)
image=Image.open(test_pic)
img=asarray(image) # use this way to load png file; use imread to load png file it will be float
img_size = img.shape
X = img.reshape(img_size[0] * img_size[1], img_size[2]) #reshape image to flat
print(X)
no_cluster=10 # number of clusters = K
km = KMeans(n_clusters=no_cluster) # Initialize KMeans
km.fit(X)
# Use the centroids to compress the image
X_compressed = km.cluster_centers_[km.labels_]
X_compressed = np.clip(X_compressed.astype('uint8'), 0, 255)

# Reshape X_recovered to have the same dimension as the original image 128 * 128 * 3
X_compressed = X_compressed.reshape(img_size[0], img_size[1], img_size[2])

im = Image.fromarray(X_compressed)
im.save("compressed_"+test_pic)
```
````

Comment: why do you expect it to be smaller?

Comment: @Aaron - welcome to CV

Answer (score 1):

I'm with @shimao because you are comparing apples and octopi.

You are converting from jpg, which is a discrete-cosine compressed transform, to a version of bitmap.  How about we compress with number of clusters equal number of original distinct levels and use that as out reference instead of the DCT compressed version?

If you want to be fun, you can use something like 7-zip to compress your outputs and get a compressed size comparison.

Disclaimer: I'm not sure ravel is going to do the job, but you get the idea.

Try something like this

```
...
no_cluster=length(np.unique(X.ravel())) # number of distinct elements

...
im.save("compressed_"+str(no_cluster) + "_" +test_pic)
```

Then try this:

```
...
no_cluster=10 # only 10 unique colors 

...
im.save("compressed_"+str(no_cluster) + "_" +test_pic)
```

And then compare the file sizes

Comment: Thanks! I guess it's because the saving part is questionable. im = Image.fromarray(X_compressed)
im.save("compressed_"+test_pic)  Theoretically, original pic has every pixel using 8 bits corresponding to RGB value, range (0,255). Totally there are 256**3 colors. Now with only 10 colors, it shouldn't use much less bits to represent the color. But converting numpy array to image might not follow that, still using 8 bits for each RGB value. And of course, it's not saving to jpg format.

Comment: If you had 8 colors then you could use a 3-bit representation.  This would require a particular array specification using Numpy "dtype" and assuring that it saved in a binary format.